# Trigger window resize on bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having sizing problems with a c3.js chart I have placed in a bootstrap collapse div. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003591/c3-chart-sizing-is-too-big-when-initially-loaded). Following the answers, I am trying to trigger a window resize each time the c3 chart is loaded, but does not seem to work. I know it's kind of a basic question (jquery ignorant), but how can I run `$(window).trigger('resize');` each time I load the chart or open the panel-collapse div?

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">                  
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse4"><center>Title</center></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div id="chart3"></div>
                <div class="panel-footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart3',
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['data1', 30],
                ['data2', 50]
            ],
            type: 'donut',
        }
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `.click()` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel-collapse collapse").click(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
  });
});
```

For the chart load, it'll depend on how you're calling it to be generated. If `c3.generate()` is the graph load function, then create another wrapping function, which calls both `c3.generate()` and `$(window).trigger('resize');` then always load the chart with that:

```
function generateAndResizeWindow(options) {
  options.onrendered = function() { $(window).trigger('resize') }; // or whatever function generates your graph
  c3.generate(options);
}
```

then call as:

```
generateAndResizeWindow({
    bindto: '#chart3',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 50]
        ],
        type: 'donut',
    }
});
```

for your example.

Comment: changed `.panel-collapse collapse` for `.panel-collapse` and worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines after your code.

```
chart.load({
  done: function() {$(window).trigger('resize');}
});
```