# A workaround of window resize for loading C3 chart in Bootstrap grid layout is not working in latest(0.4.11) version of c3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, c3.js

This issue is related to [C3 chart sizing is too big when initially loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003591/c3-chart-sizing-is-too-big-when-initially-loaded)

Solution of resizing the window still works in 0.4.10, but does not work in the latest 0.4.11 version.

Please provide me solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any solutions or comments ??

Answer (score 0):

You can control the size of the chart by setting the CSS min-width (if your chart is too small) or max-width (if your chart is too big) of the div containing the chart.